# If I build a DNS server in three different locations in the world

Tags: geolocation, domain-name-system

Does the users will connect automatically to the closer dns server or I need to set something in my records?!

Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast: "Anycast is a network addressing and routing methodology in which datagrams from a single sender are routed to the topologically nearest node in a group of potential receivers all identified by the same destination address."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just try to expand Alnitak's answer.

As Alnitak mentioned, *end-users* normally don't connect to your servers, instead users normally connect to their ISP or other public caching/recursive DNS servers (like google 8.8.8.8), which in turn connect to your authoritative servers.

Thus user which located say in Russia, but uses US-based recursive servers, for your purposes behaves as if located in US. **Usually** (I'd assume it's >90%) the aforementioned recursive servers reside close to the users themselves or at least in the same region, but not it is not **always** so.

Now, which of your DNS servers recursive servers will use: It depends on a particular nameserver software implementation (i.e. **recursive** nameserver, not your **authoritative** one) At first they will randomly try any server, later they will tend to use the "closest" (by responce time) more often and "distant" less often.

As authors of the most widely used nameserver put it:

> BIND 9 used a simple method of measurement with decay to ensure that the best known 
>   server is used to resolve queries. If one server
>   for a domain was 10 ms away and another was 80 ms, BIND 9 would use
>   the 10 ms server most often, but still periodically try the one that
>   was further away

All of it have nothing to do with DNS records, and DNS records can not change this process.

**Bottomline: Users automatically tend to use the closest server somewhat more often than others.**

In this answer I don't mention [anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) which really changes the picture, but it's price and complexity is prohibitive for many users.

Answer (score 3):

End users don't (typically) connect to your authoritative servers.

Users connect to recursive servers, which ***may*** use algorithms based on round-trip-time (RTT) to choose which authoritative servers to talk to in order to resolve your domain.

Comment: Does it's done by the "Internet root nameservers" or I need to set something. Does a US user will always connect to my DNS server in US or he can go to the UK?